# Запуск из bat под другим пользователем

Tags: bat

Как написать bat что бы из него запускался exe файл, но как бы из под другого пользователя. То есть сейчас в винде залогинен User_1, планировщик запускает bat файл и из него запускается exe под пользователем User_2. Логин и пароль User_2 известны, но система их запрашивать не должна, максимум - они могут быть прописаны в bat файле.

Comment: А к чему такие сложности ?  Вы же в планировщике можете указать учетную запись, под которой будет запущена задача.  А так есть runas, но он запрашивает пароль, нельзя передать параметром

Comment: *есть runas, но он запрашивает пароль, нельзя передать параметром* Пароль можно сохранить, используя параметр /savecred. Если пароль не сохранён - он запрашивается (так будет при первом запуске), если же сохранён (а так будет при остальных запусках) - он используется. Но есть нюанс - если пароль сохранён, то от имени этой учётки теперь можно через runas запустить любой процесс.

Comment: Ну и вполне работает `echo пароль|runas /netonly /user:user_2 filename.exe`. Впрочем, народ утверждает, что не на всех версиях Windows. Тонкости: 1) если в пароле есть спецсимволы, их придётся маскировать для корректного вывода; 2) никаких красивостей! типичная ошибка - пробел между паролем и символом пайпа.

Comment: Планировщик был указан для примера, как вижу неудачного. Система еще сложней чем кажется, поэтому хотелось упростить для объяснения, но видимо придется делать полное описание :) Есть сервер бд, на этом сервере файловая система на которой лежит bat файл который будет запускаться через сиспакет ms sql  сервера. А этот bat должен запустить программу заливающую на файловую систему данные с удаленного ресурса на который доступ есть у учетки, которой нет на сервере :):)  Зачем так сделано вопрос другой и он не в моей компетенции. Так исторически сложилось в общем :)

Comment: @Akina, вариант с `echo пароль|runas /netonly /user:user_2 filename.exe` не работает, просит пароль